# Query to search in array of objects using regex in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have my schema like below:

```
var QuestionListSchema = newSchema({
    topics: [{
        _id: false,
        topicID: Number,
        topicName: String,
        quesList: [{
            quesListID: Number,
            quesListName: String,
            _id: false,
            by: String,
            questions: [{
                questionId: Number,
                _id: false,
                question: String
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

Now I have a search box, on every input I am doing an `ajax` call by sending the input to the server (`node.js`).

So here is my query which I wrote for this operation:

```
exports.search = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.quesListName);
    QuestionList.find({
            "topics.quesList.quesListName": new RegExp(req.query.quesListName, 'i')
        },
        function(err, questionList) {
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }
            return res.status(200).json(fnData(questionList));
        });
};
```

Here in response I am getting the whole document instead of the searched data.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that `QuestionList.find` will return an `array` and assuming that `quesListName` is not unique, we can retrieve only the `quesList` where `quesListName` matches as such:

```
QuestionList.find({
        "topics.quesList.quesListName": new RegExp(req.query.quesListName, 'i')
    },
    function(err, questionList) {
        if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
        } else {

            var output = [];

            questionList.forEach(function(each_1) {

                each_1.topics.forEach(function(each_2) {

                    each_2.quesList.forEach(function(each_3) {

                       if(each_3.quesListName.toLowerCase() === req.query.quesListName.toLowerCase()) {

                            output.push(each_3);

                       }

                    });
                });
            });

            return res
                .status(200)
                .json(output);
        }
    });
```

This should return an array of objects where each object is a `quesList`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. i have tried projection object as well but i m  unable to get the only searched question list as response instead i am getting whole document

Comment: @Shikhathakur Could you please provide an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: suppose i have two objects in quesList array with quesListName as "Directive Question List " and in second object  quesListName as "Controller Question List " ,so if i search for Directive Question List i need to get only the object that has quesListName as "Directive Question List "

Comment: I have tried ur updated answer also but the thing is now im getting object as null

Comment: On second thoughts, I think what you want is to send only a part of the retrieved MongoDB documents as `response`.

Comment: Please check. @Shikhathakur

Comment: Yes i did it in the same way but the problem is in response i m getting all the quesListName which i have in the document instead of getting only searched quesListName

Comment: Please check my updated answer. (As an aside, I would advise you to rethink the schema, because this code can be much simplified).

Comment: Thanks Blaze Sahlzen, i finally got the response i needed .